# Is there a type-level way to extract properties that have default from a class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I want to extract the key names of properties in a class that have default values. Is this information available to the type system?

```js
class Foo {
  hasDefault: boolean = true
  alsoHasDefault: number = 42
  noDefault: boolean
}

// How can this be implemented?
type DefaultPropertyNames<T> = ... 

// Example output:
type FooDefaults = DefaultPropertyNames<Foo> // -> 'hasDefault' | 'alsoHasDefault'
```

Comment: No that information is not in the type system. You could create an alternate way to specify the defaults, but directly it's not available

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean by "no default value" is that the value can be undefined. Currently, your code throws a type error because `noDefault` does not contain undefined in its type definition.

So let me reframe the question:

> How do I find all of the keys in a class that are potentially undefined?

Something like this works:

```
type DefaultPropertyNames<T> = Exclude<{
    [K in keyof T]: {key: K, value: T[K] extends T[K] & {} ? true : false}
}[keyof T], {value: false}>["key"]
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oAtIBECmAZmAK4gAuAXNAEaIh5gB20AvNGQE7F7rRggR4ACVyES5Ko2IBbang6toAFgBMvRvHxFSlGnQbMAPtGKMAJoQCWjPGdQBfVKjIBPAA55oW8WQAKHeA8OVwA5MGk8CAAeABUAPkUAUQAPUGILKLQASABtAGloa2gAazwXeAJoGIBdKmRSlyo8gBpoADd+bioY-OroPGSyPHMYHry+gDIUe2gAfnYuTyoiATxHexyGiqrq1uQOkC7oFYg1uJyAIgaL6qdXDzhEbx0YNmfyf0D5UPDIqIR4AkAPRA6AAWgSAHJsBB3mRIdBjJD+IIRLCxDpIUA)

To explain a little bit:

- `T[K] & {}` removes `undefined` from a type.
- `T[K] extends T[K] & {}` tells you if undefined is in the union type
- `{[K in keyof T]: ... }[keyof T]` creates a union type from each property key
- `Exclude` lets you remove items from the union type.